# $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$ (TIFR GS $2014$)

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, product-space

Question is :

Suppose $X$ is a topological space of infinite cardinality which is homeomorphic to $X\times X$. Then which of the following is true:

- $X$ is not connected.
- $X$ is not compact
- $X$ is not homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$
- None of the above.

I guess first two options are false.

We do have possibility that product of two connected spaces is connected.

So, $X\times X$ is connected if $X$ is connected. So I guess there is no problem.

We do have possibility that product of two compact spaces is compact.

So, $X\times X$ is compact if $X$ is compact. So I guess there is no problem.

I understand that this is not the proof to exclude first two options but I guess the chance is more for them to be false.

So, only thing I have problem with is third option.

I could do nothing for that third option..

I would be thankful if some one can help me out to clear this.

Thank you :)

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is a simple counterexample for the third one.

Comment: $[0,1]^\infty{}{}$

Comment: @MikeMiller Drat, beat me to it! (As a good further exercise, it's easy to show that you can't get a simultaneous counterexample to $A$ and $C$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I had the advantage of not using words :)

Comment: Why $\mathbb{Q}$ in the *discrete* topology? The usual subspace topology, works, but it's not quite trivial to see that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \approx \mathbb{Q}$, but $\mathbb{Z}$ in the discrete = subspace topology is a better example (admittedly homeomorphic to the rationals in the discrete topology, but the latter does not directly embed into the reals). The irrationals or the Cantor set also work, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Cantor set is a counter-example to the second and third statement. Note that the Cantor set is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, hence it is homeomorphic to the product with itself.

An infinite set with the smallest topology (exactly two open sets) is a counter-example to the first statement. Martini gives a better counter-example in a comment.

Comment: ... of **infinite cardinality**. But $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ works as counterexample to the first and second statement.

Comment: @martini : about the third statement? :(

Comment: As said by martini, my space must be of infinite cardinality...

Comment: @martini, thanks I had overlooked that, I will correct this.

Comment: As Carsten wrote, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is a counterexample to the second and the third statement.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz : I was very much sure of counter examples for first and second options... I am very happy with your counter example for third case too.. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @martini : Thank you so much for your contribution :)

Comment: You are welcome. Cantor space is the first space I think of when I see $X\times X\approx X$.

Comment: Oh is it so... fine fine... I would try to understand this in detail so that this may motivate me for some other examples also.. I have not much questions at present but i would ask you if i have some problem in future...

Comment: Also $X = \mathbb{Q}$ and $X = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ are subspaces of $X$ with $X \times X$ homeomorphic to $X$.

Answer (score 10):

Fix your favorite compact connected space $X$ - then $X^\omega$ is compact, connected, and homeomorphic to its own square.

Answer (score 2):

Take the Cantor set. This gives a counterexample for B and C. For A, as Mike said in the comments, take the set $[0,1]^\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q = \prod_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ where $I_n = [0,1]$. This space is known as the Hilbert cube. It is compact and connected and satisfies $Q \times Q \approx Q$.

Note that you cannot find a single counterexample $X$ for a) and c). Assume $X$ would be such a space. Then $X$ must be homeomorphic to a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, that is, homeomorphic to an interval $J$. But $J \times J$ is not homeomorphic to $J$.